# How to run something on servlet that will continue to run after the servlet sends the response?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I am sending a jQuery ajax request to a servlet.
I want the servlet to handle the request and response.
But just before the servlet returns the response, I want it to start to run something that will continue to run after the response is returned.

Is using a new thread the best way to do it? Or something else?

Comment: after **he** return the response.??

Comment: Yes. let's say after the servlet returns the response he should write something to database

Answer (score 1):

You may use plain threads which is not the best idea. You can also use some of the thread pools provided by the standard API (see the `java.util.concurrent.Executors` class).

If you are in a Java EE environment, then it's better to use `@Asynchronous` EJBs or `javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService`.

Comment: ... not sure why this is downvoted, I see nothing wrong with the answer itself.